# NGinx sends 307 instead of 401

Tags: nginx

I've used several revers proxies over time, but NGinx blew me away with its behavior. I recently had to use NGinx after years of using HAProxy (as K8s Ingress) and I'm stuck with no solution in sight.

Right from the beginning, the behaviour was different when the session was lost. An HTTP 401 would tell the client (single page JavaScript application) to inform the user that the session was lost and he/she has to login again. Instead of sending 401 to the browser, it sends a 307 to the login page, with the wrong verb (POST) since the request that fails with 401 was a POST request.

The best way to troubleshoot would be in isolation so I installed the version from the repository (Linux Mint 20) and registered a simple reverse proxy entry in /etc/nginx/conf.d

```
server {
  listen       80;
  location / {
     proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately (or fortunately) the issue manifested itself right away: as soon as I removed the cookies and the server sends 401 "Please log in", the browser shows a 307 on the request that failed with 401.

Expected behavior:

- Browser sends "POST /ping"
- Browser receives "401 on /ping"

Current behavior:

- Browser sends "POST /ping"
- Browser receives "307 /auth" and then executes /auth with POST (not sure how it knows /auth is the login page)

Any idea how to disable this behavior?

Comment: OK, posting the question is most of the time followed by _I got it_ ... We use some custom, non-standard headers starting with "__" to identify AJAX requests and background requests - and all these are not passed to the server, which forces the server to send redirects to pages. 
I know, we should use "X-" prefix but until then, any idea how can I turn off header validation?

Comment: Well, it does not matter, changed the headers, they were not compliant anyway...lesson learned, never disobey the standards ... it might work for a while but one day some man in the middle will disagree :)

Comment: Basically, the application was sending 307 since the header "I'm an Ajax request" was not reaching the server, to reply with 307. A regular page gets "go do login page".